# How to prove $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + \pi x + 2)$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I am confused about how to prove that  $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + \pi x + 2)$ is a field. How would you go about doing that?
Thanks

Comment: $\pi^2>4 \cdot 2=8$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For any field $F$, $F[X] / (P(X))$ is a field if and only if $P(X)$ is irreducible over $F$.

Your polynomial is quadratic, a quadratic is irreducible over  a field exactly when it doesn't have roots in the field.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+\pi{x}+2)$ is not a field. This is because the discriminant of the quadratic is $\pi^2-8$, which is a positive real number.

Comment: Thank you! Got it